auditd rule for delete does not work via samba anymore
I was testing auditd rules and have a simple rule for deletes:
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S unlink,unlinkat -F dir=/mnt/user/home/

I'm not sure what changed but the rule seems to work differently now. This is the only rule I have. I was testing it the other day deleting a file via an SMB share and it would log the event just fine. Now it only seems to log the delete event when I delete it locally. I can't figure what I am overlooking? I am on Slackware and previously installed audit-4.0.1-x86_64-2cf.txz from slackers.it. It was recently removed and replaced with audit-4.0.1-x86_64-3cf.txz. That's the only thing I can think of. I'm looking into that. Any other idea on what it might be?
